# Billing Account with Indian Credit Card

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

Looks like Indian Credit/Debit Cards are not supported by GCP https://support.google.com/a/answer/3401127?hl=en

What are the alternatives ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question but either looking for billing support or recommendation of a cloud service or an international prepaid credit card provider.

Answer (score 0):

Each Google Cloud Projects is entitled to receive free billing and payments support. You can get more details on how to contact billing by visiting the [Billing Support doc](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing).